# How to get records from a table with the help of a where clause and a variable

Tags: mysql

The following fucntion is used to get all records from a sql table where the name( this is a column) is equal to temp(A variable which has been assigned)

But when I run the function it shows

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'temp' in 'where clause'
```

THE CODE IS:

```
def filter():

global temp

temp = f_dob.get()
print(temp)

my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mk WHERE name = temp")

result=my_cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:

    print(row) 

    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
```

I am writing the code on sublime text editor and running it on git bash

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `temp` Python variable to the query:

```py
temp = f_dob.get()
sql = "SELECT * FROM mk WHERE name = %s"
my_cursor.execute(sql, (temp,))
result = my_cursor.fetchall()
```

In addition, you should be careful to open your MySQL database cursor in prepared statement mode.  So, your code should look something like this:

```py
my_cursor = conn.cursor(prepared=True)
```